# Should I let chronic training load drop (as in stop training) to end my current level of tiredness or continue riding?

Tags: training

I currently feel very tired yet have not been doing much interns of high mileage, I have however entered a Tuesday night tt series which is usually 10 miles but the week it was a 25 mile tt. I feel particularly burnt out despite the low mileage I have accumulated.

Should I wait till my chronic training load and acute training load drops and start again with lsd rides and attempt to build my form up from the beginning again?

Comment: What kind of TSS were you carrying into the TT series, were your ATL and CTL changing rapidly, and what was your IF for the TT?

Comment: Probably first off you should schedule yourself for a Dr's checkup.  Get the basic blood tests, etc.  You could have anything from low iron to mono.  Also, describe your pain level.

Comment: Vote to close.  Too broad. we need much more information (op's experiance, age, current training program etc) to provide a useful answer. Its bordering on medical advice - @Daniel has the right answer....

Comment: It should be noted that this time of year a lot of people suffer from "Frühjahrsmüdigkeit" or "spring fever", a sort of malaise presumed to be related to "seasonal affective disorder".  But another condition to consider is sleep apnea -- it's primary symptom is often a sense of fatigue.

Comment: The question doesn't give quite enough information to determine whether this is actually health-related or a result of training overload -- that's why I was asking for clarification. If the previous load was light then I agree it's health-related and would think it not in the purview of bicycles.stackexchange. If the load had been ramping up quickly then it could be a training question.

Comment: Annoyingly I have switched from training peaks to golden cheetah this week and have yet set it all up yet. But prior to that my tss has been from first week of having a power meter @ 27/01/2014

Comment: TSS per week:
232, 50, 199, 301, 131, 200, 395, 371, 335, 448 (tt series starts here with an if of 0.88 and my fatigue would drop by 11 points.), 418, 428, 224, 468, 325

Answer (score 2):

At the end of one particularly hard road racing season, I felt pretty tired as well. I decided to take about 3-4 days completely off the bike and by the end of that I felt good again and ready to go. If you haven't even taken that off you might try. Also be sure to eat right and get enough sleep if you're not.

But everyone's body is different. Attempting to build form back up "from the beginning" seems like a strong initial reaction if you haven't tried more simple R&R first.